# Displaying a virtual folder/file representing the parent directory in a QTreeView displaying the directory using a QFileSystemModel

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyside6, pyqt6

I am trying to implement a file viewer that, when double clicking a folder, sets this folder as the root. To allow the user to go back, I want to display a virtual file/directory that when double clicked sets the root back to the parent of the current open folder.

Concretely, I want to display / have the following:

```
Folder A (~/path/to/this/open/folder)
   -> Parent
   -> Folder B
   -> File A
   -> ...
```

After double clicking Folder B, I would then have

```
Folder B (~/path/to/this/open/folder)
   -> Parent
   -> ...
```

With Parent now linking to folder A.

I have considered multiple things: subclassing QFileSystemModel or QTreeView, subclassing from QAbstractItemModel, using mkdir on an instance of QFileSystemModel. Since the parent folder is purely a UI thing, I guess it would make the most sense to subclass QTreeView but even then I am a bit stuck on how to do it. Specifically, adding a virtual parent file/directory (and, but of less importance, displaying the path information of the open folder). Setting the root to the index of the double clicked folder I was able to do.

For completness sake, I have distilled a minimal working example of my current code:

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from typing import Union

from PySide6.QtCore import QModelIndex, QDir, QSortFilterProxyModel, QPersistentModelIndex
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTreeView, QFileSystemModel


class CustomProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):

    NAME_COLUMN = 0

    def filterAcceptsColumn(self, source_column: int, source_parent: Union[QModelIndex, QPersistentModelIndex]) -> bool:
        return source_column == self.NAME_COLUMN

    def isDir(self, proxy_index: QModelIndex):
        source_index = self.mapToSource(proxy_index)
        source_model = self.sourceModel()

        if source_model and source_index.isValid():
            return source_model.isDir(source_index)
        else:
            return False


def on_folder_double_clicked(proxy, tree, index):
        if proxy.isDir(index):
            tree.setRootIndex(index)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    tree = QTreeView()
    tree.header().hide()

    path = QDir.rootPath() + 'Users/'

    filesystem_model = QFileSystemModel()
    filesystem_model.setReadOnly(True)
    filesystem_model.setRootPath(path)

    proxy = CustomProxyModel()
    proxy.setSourceModel(filesystem_model)

    source_index = filesystem_model.index(path, 0)

    tree.setModel(proxy)
    on_folder_double_clicked(proxy, tree, proxy.mapFromSource(source_index))
    tree.doubleClicked.connect(partial(on_folder_double_clicked, proxy, tree))

    tree.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: For future reference, consider that questions normally require a valid [mre], in order to simplify the process of understanding your issue to people that may want to help you by providing their answers: having a valid MRE makes easier to reproduce the issue, so that we can focus on the actual problem with a valid starting point to provide a proper answer, instead of being distracted by trying to reproduce the problem or having to reproduce it on our own. For instance, we know nothing about the `SidePanel` class, nor how `MainWindowPresenter` is created and its arguments are used.

Comment: @musicamante I have updated the post with a minimal working example distilled from my code. But, in essence, the functionality that I want to achieve / my question is about, is not yet part of it as I am struggling to get that going.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually ended up writing it from scratch for my answer, but remember that having a proper MRE can improve the possibility of answers (possibly because a good question gets more votes, which increase the post visibility).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a model/view pair cannot just consider the parent for the proxy filter, as the object hierarchy must be properly understood.

Most importantly, in order to show the "parent" folder:

- the view should use the parent of *that* parent as its root item;
- the proxy should only filter *out* the siblings of any item of the "parent" and do the same for all parent items above it;
- the proxy should *always* show items that *contain* the "parent" and filter out anything else, except when the root path is the file system root (`/` on *nix and "Computer" on Windows);

Unfortunately, your ideas for implementing this are not acceptable:

- subclassing QFileSystemModel or QTreeView is not sufficient nor valid:

  - models should never be aware about the state of the view(s) connected to them; while you can try to create a carefully crafted system that allows the model to directly interact with its view, such approach is risky at best, and making it reliable may be very difficult;
  - views don't have control on their models (just like models don't have control on the views displaying them), meaning that the view cannot (easily) directly decide what to show; even if you try to use functions like [`setRowHidden()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtreeview.html#setRowHidden), that may become quite difficult to implement with a QFileSystemModel, because files and folders can be created/deleted/moved/renamed outside of the application, resulting in unexpected behavior;
- subclassing from QAbstractItemModel may be a possibility, but you'd still need to have an underlying file system model that promptly changes the Qt item model upon changes; implementing all that may be extremely complicated and not worth the effort;
- using `mkdir` on an instance of QFileSystemModel is completely inappropriate, and for a lot of reasons:

  - what if the path already contains a directory with the same name?
  - unless you set a proper order for the items, the "dummy" directory may be placed at a wrong index due to the sorting order (for example, `_` normally comes before than `.`);

Note that QFileSystemModel already provides a similar feature, common in some file browsers that inherit command line behavior: the `..` ("dot-dot") path corresponds to the parent folder.

By default, QFileSystemModel does *not* show such virtual items, since it's initial filter uses `QDir.NoDotDot, so it's necessary to call [`setFilter()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfilesystemmodel.html#setFilter) with the current filter options while *removing* that flag:

```py
model.setFilter(model.filter() & ~QDir.Filter.NoDotDot)
```

With the above, if you are not interested in providing the possibility of expanding/collapsing of directory branches, then you can just use a basic QListView.

Regardless the view you will eventually use, the above won't be without issues, though; for example:

- while the `..` item is normally on top of a directory listing, in some cases it may be shown *below* some items (also depending on the OS);
- sorting the model might show the `..` at the wrong place;
- `..` is also shown for the root path;

A possible implementation will use a QSortFilterProxyModel subclass with an underlying QFileSystemModel:

```py
class FileSystemModelDotDot(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    rootPathChanged = pyqtSignal(str)
    rootIndexChanged = pyqtSignal(QModelIndex)
    def __init__(self, path=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.fsModel = QFileSystemModel()
        self.fsModel.setRootPath(path or QDir.homePath())
        self.fsModel.setFilter(self.fsModel.filter() & ~QDir.Filter.NoDotDot)
        self.setSourceModel(self.fsModel)

        self.fsModel.rootPathChanged.connect(self.emitRootChanged)

        self.sort(0, Qt.SortOrder.AscendingOrder)

    def emitRootChanged(self, path):
        self.rootPathChanged.emit(path)
        self.rootIndexChanged.emit(self.rootIndex())

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        # if only the first column should be visible, there is no point in
        # using filterAcceptsColumn
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        if (
            role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DecorationRole 
            and index.row() == 0 
            and index.column() == 0
            and super().data(index, Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole) == '..'
        ):
            return QApplication.style().standardIcon(
                QStyle.StandardPixmap.SP_FileDialogToParent)

        return super().data(index, role)

    def indexForPath(self, path):
        return self.mapFromSource(self.fsModel.index(path))

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        # always hide the ".." for the system root path and for sub
        # directories of the current path
        if self.fsModel.index(row, 0, parent).data() == '..' and (
            not parent.parent().isValid()
            or parent != self.fsModel.index(self.fsModel.rootPath())
        ):
            return False
        return super().filterAcceptsRow(row, parent)

    def hasChildren(self, parent):
        # prevent showing the arrow and expanding the ".." item
        return parent.data() != '..' and super().hasChildren(parent)

    def isDir(self, index):
        return self.fsModel.isDir(self.mapToSource(index))

    def filePath(self, index):
        return self.fsModel.filePath(self.mapToSource(index))

    def lessThan(self, left, right):
        # ".." is always the first in the list, no matter the order
        if left.column() == 0:
            if left.data() == '..':
                return True
            elif right.data() == '..':
                return False
        elif left.siblingAtColumn(0).data() == '..':
            return True
        elif right.siblingAtColumn(0).data() == '..':
            return False
        return left.row() < right.row()

    def rootIndex(self):
        return self.indexForPath(self.fsModel.rootPath())

    def rootPath(self):
        return self.fsModel.rootPath()

    def setRootPath(self, path):
        if isinstance(path, QDir):
            path = path.path()
        if QFileInfo.exists(path) and QFileInfo(path).isReadable():
            self.fsModel.setRootPath(QDir.cleanPath(path))
        return self.rootIndex()

    def sort(self, column, order):
        # sort the source, not the proxy
        self.fsModel.sort(column, order)
        # required to force lessThan
        super().sort(column, Qt.SortOrder.AscendingOrder)
```

Here is how it works:

- the file system model is "private" to the proxy, as there's no need to use an external object; this also makes it simpler to access it from the proxy functions and overrides;
- `sort()` actually sorts the *source* model, while keeping the proxy sorting intact, but still allowing usage of `lessThan()`, which can be used to ensure that the `..` path is always the first item on top;
- the custom `setRootPath()` function sets the root path of the file system model, if it is accessible;
- if the fs model actually changes its root path (`rootPathChanged` is emitted) then two custom signals are emitted accordingly, specifically the new "root" index (`rootIndexChanged`);
- the view connects to the above signal with its `setRootIndex()`, so that it automatically changes the root when the model does;

An example of usage:

```py
class DirTreeViewBase(QTreeView):
    pathChanged = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, path=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setExpandsOnDoubleClick(False)
        self.header().hide()

        self.proxy = FileSystemModelDotDot(path)

        self.setModel(self.proxy)
        self.setRootIndex(self.proxy.rootIndex())
        self.proxy.rootPathChanged.connect(self.pathChanged)
        self.proxy.rootIndexChanged.connect(self.setRootIndex)

        self.doubleClicked.connect(self.setPathIndex)

    def currentPath(self):
        return self.proxy.rootPath()

    def setPathIndex(self, index):
        if self.proxy.isDir(index):
            path = QDir(self.proxy.filePath(index)).path()
            self.proxy.setRootPath(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    def updatePath(path):
        win.statusBar().showMessage('Current path: ' + path)

    win = QMainWindow()

    view = DirTreeViewBase('/tmp')
    win.setCentralWidget(view)
    view.pathChanged.connect(updatePath)
    updatePath(view.currentPath())

    win.resize(400, 600)
    r = win.geometry()
    r.moveCenter(app.primaryScreen().geometry().center())
    win.setGeometry(r)
    win.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate and insightful answer.